# how to find out rows that have one or more values as zero in any column of data set in python

Tags: python, dataframe

Suppose say I have a dataframe with 20 rows(observations) and 4 columns.

Out of 20 rows, 5 rows have zeroes in 2 columns.
How to find out which rows have zeroes as values in any column of dataframe in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can check which elements are zeros with `df == 0`. Then you can apply the `.any` across `axis` `1` in order to see which rows have any column equal to `0`:

```
(df == 0).any(axis=1)
```

If you want to get the row indexes for all elements where that is true, you can do something like this:

```
df[(df == 0).any(axis=1)].index
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this to get the list of indices of rows which have values 0:

```
df[(df.values == 0).any(axis=1)].index.values.tolist()
```